# DrawImage method of Graphics class is making unintended clippings in the original image

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, picturebox, drawimage

I have this code to add bitmap to a picturebox

```
pictureBoxTemp.Image = finalImage;
```

Where finalImage variable is a bitmap holding the image. When I use this method. The result is good. Here is the image for this code:[image]

And then, I decided to add zoom functionality so it is necessary to add a paint event on my picturebox.. This is my code for the paint event:

```
 protected void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e, ref ZoomInfo imageZoom)
 {
     //Conditions to avoid to proceed further.
     if (((PictureBox)sender).Image == null) { return; }

     float futurePosX = (imageZoom.translateX) * (1 - imageZoom.zoom) / imageZoom.zoom;
     float futurePosY = (imageZoom.translateY) * (1 - imageZoom.zoom) / imageZoom.zoom;

     Graphics g = e.Graphics;

     g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
     g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
     g.ScaleTransform(imageZoom.zoom, imageZoom.zoom);

     g.DrawImage(((PictureBox)sender).Image, futurePosX, futurePosY);
 }
```

By default, `futurePosY` and `futurePosX` are both 0 so `g.DrawImage()` will draw it in 0,0 position. When paint is called, image is changed to this:
[image]

Notice that there is now a black region on the bottom of the image which means that the image is clipped.

I don't know for now why `DrawImage()` is clipping my image but when use `pictureBox.Image = Bitmap` again, the image fits perfectly on pictureBox. Any suggestions how to correct this?

Comment: What is value of imageZoom.zoom?

Comment: value at first of imageZoom.zoom is 1.. So futurePosX and futurePosY are both 0 at first. I believe this should have no bearing on result of DrawImage since both x and y are 0 initially.

Comment: If your imageZoom.zoom is 1 what is the sence of `g.ScaleTransform(imageZoom.zoom, imageZoom.zoom);`

Comment: It is 1 INITIALY. so it will change onMouseWheel event.

Comment: And just to clarify.. removing ScaleTransform will yield the same result with clipped lower pixel on image so I think zoom is not the issue here

Comment: try to remove `PixelOffsetMode` or set it to `default` or `none`

Comment: I tried that already.. same result.. clipped pixel at the bottom

Comment: Check the x and y of the image outside your paint method. Maybe it is not 0, 0 by default. Maybe PictureBox applies a small offset. just an idea

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what do you mean by "x and y of the image outside your paint method"?

Comment: What is the `SizeMode` of the PictureBox set to ? If it is something like `StretchImage` then your image would be scaled to fill the available space when the `Image` property is set. The Paint event you are writing would then draw the image at its actual dimensions which could be smaller than the available height.

Comment: I already tried all possible values for SizeMode but still the same. Thank you though.

Comment: You must stop using the PictureBox.Image property.  The Graphics object you get in OnPaint() was setup to draw the original image.  But that is not what you are trying to draw.  Simply add a private field to the form class of type Image instead.  If you do anything that should cause a redraw, like zooming, then simply call pictureBoxTemp.Invalidate()

Comment: @Hans Passant. Can you please elaborate this answer even with just a small code snippet? Thank you